# Customizing optional arguments to include their own positional argument(s)

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I would like to have a script which takes command-line arguments including flag options which take positional arguments themselves. I might expect the command line input to look something like

```
$ ./script.py [-o <file1> <file2> ...] inputfile
```

The official [argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/argparse.html) most similarly talks about

```
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbosity", type=int, help="increase output verbosity")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

where the user inputs a single positional sub-argument (perhaps out of a set of choices) following the `-v` flag. This positional sub-argument is then stored in `args.verbosity`.

Thus it appears the flag's argument needs to be included in the same `add_argument()` line. Can you declare any special name for this sub-argument's variable (say, `args.outputfile1`)? Can the flag take more than one sub-argument? Can you adjust how the sub-variable looks in the help menu? By default it is something like`-o OUTPUT, --output OUTPUT   Save output data to a file OUTPUT`. Can we change it to read `-o <SomethingElse>`?

Is there any more documentation which discusses this aspect?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want.  How is the parser supposed to differentiate between the `output` file list and the ensuing `input` file?  I'm suspect that you're trying to do something beyond the capabilities of `argparse`; you'll have to write your own parsing function for the stronger grammar you envision.

Comment: How output differentiates from input is irrelevant; I am just giving an example of how something may look. It is possible argparse does not have the functionality I want, but I was curious if this is possible with existing python modules because I have seen many CLI tools that have better looking help menus and seemingly more functionality from CLI options and arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a definition like:

```
parser.add_argument('-o','--output', dest='output_file_name', nargs='+')
```

you can give a commandline like:

```
$ ./script.py -o file1 file2
```

and get `args.output_file_name` equal to `['file1','file2']`.  The '+' means one or more arguments (other `nargs` values are documented).

But

```
$ ./script.py -o file1 file2 an_input_file
```

where 'an_input_file' goes to a positional argument is harder to achieve.  '*' is greedy, taking everything, leaving nothing for the positional.  It's better to define another optional

```
parser.add_argument('-i','--input')

$ ./script.py -o file1 file2 -i an_input_file
```

If the '-o' is defined as an 'append' Action, you can use:

```
$ ./script.py -o file1 -o file2 -i an_input_file
```

In general you get the best control by using optionals.  Positionals, because they 'parse' by position, not value, are harder to use in fancy combinations.

The `metavar` parameter lets you change the `help` display.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed interface is pretty unusual. It's more common to have people specify the same option multiple times, because tt's hard to distinguish `./script.py [-o file1 file2 ...]` input file from `./script.py [-o file1] file2 inputfile`. That might not be an issue yet, but as you add options or god-forbid arguments, your unusual design will become an issue.

I would recommend doing one of the following solutions:

**1. Repeat the option flag**

`./script.py -o file1 -o file2 inputfile`

**2. Make your option a boolean flag**

Change your API so `-o` indicates that all arguments except the last one are output files:
`./script.py -o output1 output2 ... inputfileislast`